# Is it possible to get my Wacom tablet mapped across multiple monitors in KDE

Tags: linux, kde, usability, wacom, kscreen

The default KDE wacom setting is that the pen cursor follows the "active screen".

That means that if you're using the pen as your pointing device, to click on something on another monitor you have to somehow click somewhere in the other monitor to make it "active", and only then can you use the pen. This means you have to grab a mouse or use another pointing device every time you move the cursor from one screen to another. This is so klunky as to be almost totally unusable. The only other option in the KDE Graphics Tablet settings is to map it to only one of the screens.

Is there a way to configure it to map across both screens, like you can with Gnome and other DEs or indeed Windows or Mac?

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I updated to Plasma 6. Looking on the [KDE Wacom support](https://github.com/KDE/wacomtablet) I found the *Hardware support* section, so I checked my device using:

```
$ xsetwacom list devices
```

But I got an error since this only works in X11 and I was running Wayland.

I changed my environment to X11 in the Login Screen (and set it to default in Settings > Colors & Themes > SDDM > Behavior) and now the tablet is mapped to all the screens. The *Drawing Tablet* menu in the System Settings also changed to *Graphic Tablet* with different configurations.

I know the goal is for Wayland to replace the X server on the majority of Linux desktops, but this is the only workaround I found to use my tablet correctly.